# why can't $module be used as a variable name? in jq

Tags: syntax, jq, variable-names

Is this behaviour of jq, w.r.t the non-allowed use of $module as a variable name, specified anywhere?

```
$ jq -n --arg 'module' 'X' '$module'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected module, expecting IDENT or __loc__ (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
$module 
jq: 1 compile error
```

My expectation is that jq would print "X", but this is not the case. Why?

Answer (score 1):

In jq 1.6 and earlier, keywords cannot be used in $-variable names.
This is mentioned on the [the jq wiki](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/wiki/How-to:-Avoid-Pitfalls#keywords), where the following list of keywords is given:

```
__loc__ and as break catch def elif else end 
foreach if import include label module
or reduce then try
```

The list of keywords for any particular version of jq can be derived from the lexer.l file, the “master” version of which is https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/lexer.l

——

The restriction was removed in the development version of jq in 2019 by https://github.com/jqlang/jq/commit/c72ed135e4f1b5a02a8fb3f6cd46f27513ecab2a
and thus will no longer exist in jq 1.7

Comment: Hopefully someone with better _fu_ can derive it better than this: [`curl -s https://github.com/jqlang/jq/blob/master/src/lexer.l | jq -r 'reduce .payload.blob.rawLines[] as $line ([]; . += [$line|select(test("^\"[$_a-z]+\".*return [A-Z_]+;") and (test("^\"(true|false|null)\"")|not))|capture("\"(?<out>[$_a-z]+)\"")|.out])|sort|.[]'`](https://jqplay.org/s/RbW0VFrrKlh "link to jqplay.org -->").